Webpack 5: Multi-page site configuration problems
I am trying to figure out how to use webpack 5 for a multi-page site. It is currently placing most of the files as expected into the 'dist' folder however, when I am working in development, my SCSS/CSS files are being ignored. I have also dropped my 'dist' folder into a server and, the JS files are there but the JS isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.
In the index.js and purchaselinks_object.js files I am also importing the .scss file from the correct location,
import '../scss/main.scss';

webpack common
  const path = require('path');
  const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

  const pages = ['index', 'products'];

  module.exports = {
    entry: {
      index: {
        import: ['./src/js/index.js'],
        dependOn: 'shared',
      },
      products: {
        import: ['./src/js/purchaselinks_object.js', './src/js/custom_select.js'],
        dependOn: 'shared',
      },
      shared: 'js-cookie',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource',
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/i,
          use: 'html-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
      },
    },
    plugins: [].concat(
      pages.map(
        page =>
          new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: `./src/${page}.html`,
            filename: `${page}.html`,
            chunks: [page],
          }),
      ),
    ),
    output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      clean: true,
      assetModuleFilename: pathData => {
        const filepath = path
          .dirname(pathData.filename)
          .split('/')
          .slice(1)
          .join('/');
        return `${filepath}/[name][ext][query]`;
      },
    },
  };


webpack dev
  const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
  const common = require('./webpack.common');

  module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      static: './dist',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
            { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
            { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  });

webpack production
  const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
  const common = require('./webpack.common');
  const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

  module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
      }),
    ],
  });

I have redone this configuration multiple times. I consistently have been getting the following files in my dist folder
index.bundle.js
index.css
products.bundle.js
products.css
shared.bundle.js

I also see them in the .html documents as expected within the dist folder. What I am not getting is a runtime.bundle.js file which before I tried turning this into a multipage site, I was getting. Not sure if that is the difference.

you can try to use the modern html-bundler-webpack-plugin. This plugin makes Webpack config for multi-page very easily. See the Multiple pages with Webpack example how it works. Please create a small repo on GitHub with your use case and I help you to configure the Webpack.

I found this late last night and was going to try this, this morning. Do you know if it handles babel behind the scenes?

this is a basic example without any complications, but you can self add a babel rule in the config

I am still having issues. My JS and CSS files are all being seen as MIME files and not executing. https://github.com/enuber/test_newwebpack.git here is the repo. Any suggestions and help is appreciated.

Think I may have figured it out. Went back to a super simple set up and started adding things in slowly. For SCSS you need to have one more step in the process. Need to have  postcss-loader between css-loader and sass-loader.
I also successfully added in babel and checked it. Will try to revise the above repo and see what happens.

Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it. I figured some of it out myself but, the rest really helped me out.

Just noting here...if anyone is looking for similar help, I have updated the repo above. This includes babel, support for a couple other image types (gif and webp), and does auto prefixing and minimizing css in the build. I also prefer my image files to end up in the same folder format so I have added that in as well.
